# How to set Component displayName in arrow function HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I'm trying figure out how to add displayname to my HOC and remove comment *eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name* from following code:

```js
const withMyHOC = () => <P extends MyProps>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>):
    React.FunctionComponent<P> => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
    return (props: P): ReactElement => (
        <MyComponent>
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading */}
            <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </MyComponent>);
};
```

I found below solution:

```js
const withMyHOC = () => <P extends MyProps>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>):
    React.FunctionComponent<P> => {
    const innerHOC = (props: P): ReactElement => (
        <MyComponent>
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading */}
            <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </MyComponent>);
    return innerHOC;
};
```

But I think it not looks good.

Answer (score 0):

```
const decorate = <P extends object>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P>,
    displayName?:string
  ): React.FC<P> => ({
      ...props
  }: P) =>{
      const WithName = withStyles({})(Component as React.FC) 
      WithName.displayName = displayName
    return <WithName {...props as P} />
  }
```

And then use like this:

(Note! need to be outside a component)

```
const MyComp = decorate(Compo, "MyComp")
```